# XMLReader reads a few values correctly, then turns up blank

Tags: c#, xml

Good day, in my project I save all my data into an XML file. When you start up the program it reads from said XML file (Name: ProjectList.xml).

I have searched, and read through quite a few "similar" problems, where I've tried their solutions and it still came up with the same.

So, the problem:

I can read the 'ID' and 'Employee ID' values fine, I can even read my employee data from another part of the software using the same code and it works 100%. But for some reason when it has to read the TimeStart and TimeStop values, the string returns as "" (Empty).

I've had a similar problem reading pure Integers from XML but that was fixed with

```
ReadElementContentAsInt()
```

Tried the similar

```
ReadElementContentAsDateTime()
```

seeing as it's a `DateTime` value directly written from `DateTime.ToString()`. But it also returns as "" (Empty).

I welcome any suggestions, other than to move away from XML :P

Sample Code:

```
if (File.Exists(FileName))
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FileName))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.IsStartElement())
        {
            switch (reader.Name)
            {
                ... (Shortening example of code for the sake of relevancy)
                case "TimeStart":
                    string str = reader.ReadOuterXml();
                        DateTime t = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    _ProjectData[count].TimeStamps[c].Start = t;
                    break;
                case "TimeStop":
                        t = DateTime.ParseExact(reader.Value.Trim(), "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        _ProjectData[count].TimeStamps[c].Stop = t;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample XML file:

```
<Projects>
    <Project>
        <ID>D11</ID>
        <TimeStamps>
            <TimeStamp>
                <EmployeeID>0</EmployeeID>
                <TimeStart>2016/05/24 8:47:30 PM</TimeStart>
                <TimeStop>2016/05/24 8:47:32 PM</TimeStop>
            </TimeStamp>
        </TimeStamps>
    </Project>
    <Project>
        <ID>D12</ID>
        <TimeStamps>
            <TimeStamp>
                <EmployeeID>0</EmployeeID>
                <TimeStart>2016/05/24 8:51:06 PM</TimeStart>
                <TimeStop>2016/05/24 9:31:27 PM</TimeStop>
            </TimeStamp>
            <TimeStamp>
                <EmployeeID>0</EmployeeID>
                <TimeStart>2016/05/24 9:47:44 PM</TimeStart>
                <TimeStop>2016/05/24 10:51:11 PM</TimeStop>
            </TimeStamp>
        </TimeStamps>
    </Project>
</Projects>
```

Comment: is there any reason you have to use `XmlReader`? It's a very low-level API.  LINQ to XML would be a much nicer solution.

Comment: @CharlesMager I must admit, I only use code that is familiar to me (hence using XmlReader), and have not touched LINQ at all due to never really needing to or well, understanding the need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ReadElementContentAsString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readelementcontentasstring(v=vs.110).aspx) to get string value. `Value` property itself is empty because `NodeType` property is `Element` and reader will always return empty string in that case.
Alternatively you can try

```
reader.Read();
string str = reader.Value;
DateTime t = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    _ProjectData[count].TimeStamps[c].Start = t;
```

to set reader in correct position.

Comment: Also returns empty string, I honestly can't tell you why, but it would seem that both ReadElementContentAsString() and ReadElementContentAsDateTime() returns an empty string., the same as Value

Comment: I've tried you example and was able to reproduce empty string in Value property.  ReadElementContentAsString() was working for me

Comment: Extremely odd, tried using ReadElementContentAsString() now again, as opposed to failing earlier. Should've kept a screenshot cause it's returning the value correctly now. (Must be karma getting at me.)

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to XML is a really nice API that lets you easily query your XML using LINQ queries.  For example, this query would let you find a Project by ID and get the (only) timestamp's start time - but you could write any sort of query, really:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

var startForD11 = (DateTime)doc
    .Descendants("Project")
    .Where(x => (string) x.Element("ID") == "D11")
    .Descendants("TimeStart")
    .Single();
```

Or get all the timestamps:

```
var timestamps =
    from project in doc.Descendants("Project")
    let projectId = (int) project.Element("ID")
    from timestamp in project.Descendants("Timestamp")
    select new
    {
        ProjectId = projectId,
        EmployeeId = (int) timestamp.Element("EmployeeID"),
        TimeStart = (DateTime) timestamp.Element("TimeStart"),
        TimeEnd = (DateTime) timestamp.Element("TimeEnd"),
    };
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z9Kelp) for a working demo. It's probably worth further investigation if you've not come across it.

Comment: Is there a similar way to replace XmlWriter using LINQ? This is indeed very useful and I will have to look deeper into it. Much appreciated.

Comment: Yep, you can either edit an existing `XDocument` or create a new one, add elements and attributes to it and call `Save`.

Comment: In your example "D11" is predefined and set in the code. Say there is about 40 projects and I need to load all of them into seperate objects in a list without knowing any details except for the structure, At the moment the XmlReader "loads" every object from the file and places it in it's correct place. Everytime it reads <Project>, adds a new project to a list called ProjectData. Within that it changes the new project ID to whatever it reads. Then moves on to the timestamps, which in its own is a new list of objects consisting of an object containing <EmployeeID>, <TimeStart> and <TimeStop>.

Comment: That's still pretty easy.  The second example I gave reads every timestamp for every project. It wouldn't be hard to query to whatever structure you need, really.

Comment: While the answer that Denis gave fixed my problem, I will definitely follow your advice and look into moving over to LINQ.Thank you again for your insight and it still fits perfectly to my statement of "other than to move away from XML"